# Assign objects as variable in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following json which is POST data to my script:-

```
{
    "type":"vehicles:motorised",
    "data":[
       {
          "type":"motorised:cars",
          "data":{
             "make":"Audi",
             "model":"A4"
          }
       },
       {
          "type":"motorised:vans",
          "data":{
             "make":"Ford",
             "model":"Transit"
          }
       },
       {
          "type":"motorised:bikes",
          "data":{
             "make":"Honda",
             "model":"Fireblade"
          }
       }
    ]
 }
```

In php, I am simply doing the following to get this data and convert to a php array.

```
$jsonContent = file_get_contents("php://input");

$jsonData = json_decode($jsonContent, true);
```

This works and provides the following if I var_dump($jsonData):-

```
array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(18) "vehicles:motorised"
    ["data"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(14) "motorised:cars"
        ["data"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["make"]=>
          string(4) "Audi"
          ["model"]=>
          string(2) "A4"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(14) "motorised:vans"
        ["data"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["make"]=>
          string(4) "Ford"
          ["model"]=>
          string(7) "Transit"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(15) "motorised:bikes"
        ["data"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["make"]=>
          string(5) "Honda"
          ["model"]=>
          string(9) "Fireblade"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I figured I could use the following to create an object for each 'type' of motorised vehicle, like so:-

```
$cars = $jsonData['data'][0]['data'];
$vans = $jsonData['data'][1]['data'];
$bikes = $jsonData['data'][2]['data'];
```

This works fine. I can print_r($cars) and get the cars array perfectly. However, Using 0, 1 and 2 is confusing and would fall apart if, for some reason, my json was in a different order, therefore for example '1' may hold bikes and '2' may hold cars, etc. So i would like to go about this a better way, something like:-

```
if ($jsonData['data'][0]['type'] == "motorised:cars") {
    $cars = $jsonData['data'][0]['data'];
} elseif ($jsonData['data'][1]['type'] == "motorised:cars") {
    $cars = $jsonData['data'][1]['data'];
} elseif ($jsonData['data'][2]['type'] == "motorised:cars") {
    $cars = $jsonData['data'][2]['data'];
}
```

As you can tell, this quickly gets out of hand and will probably fall over somewhere.

As the 'type' value will always be correct in this instance (motorised:cars, motorised:vans, motorised:bikes) so should just be a case of getting the object 'data' from that 'type' key.

Is there a better - at least correct - way of doing this? I tried using a foreach, but didn't get far before my lack of knowledge failed me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a map indexed by `type`. This can be done with a simple loop, or with [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce):

```
$map = array_reduce($jsonData['data'], function ($map, $entry) {
  $map[$entry['type']] = $entry['data'];
  return $map;
}, []);
```

Then use it simply like this:

```
$cars = $map['motorised:cars'];
$vans = $map['motorised:vans'];
$bikes = $map['motorised:bikes'];
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/8foHN**

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks!